# Receive & Respond to Twilio Text Message with Node js express graphql

Tags: graphql, twilio

I followed the [Twilio instructions](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/10/how-to-receive-and-respond-to-a-text-message-with-node-js-express-and-twilio.html) to setup receive & respond to a text message as in the URL below which uses a Rest Post. It works. Great.

```
app.post('/sms', (req, res) => {

  // Start our TwiML response.
  const twiml = new MessagingResponse();

  // Add a text message.
  const msg = twiml.message('Check out this sweet owl!');

  // Add a picture message.
  msg.media('https://demo.twilio.com/owl.png');

  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/xml'});
  res.end(twiml.toString());
});
```

I then wanted to convert the REST POST to a graphql POST to be consistent with my code base. I set it up, and my graphql POST responds with the following format which is not xml (which I believe Twilio requires) but json as per graphql. Thus, I can see the response move through the system but Twilio registers an error. If I'm correct, is there a way for Twilio to process the graphql json response or for me to adjust graphql to return xml rather than json (as below)?

My latest graphql attempt wraps the rest post in a graphql query as such.

```
sms: async () => {
      // console.log(request, response);

      const { MessagingResponse } = require("twilio").twiml;

      const twiml = new MessagingResponse();

      twiml.message("The Robots are coming! Head for the hills!");

      let test = "";

      return axios({
        method: "post",
        url: "https://2b52-98-38-82-19.ngrok.io/sms",
        responseType: 'text/xml'
      })
        .then(res => test = res.data)
        // .then(function (response) {
        //   console.log('axios response =', response);
        //   return twiml.toString();
        // })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        });

      }
    }
```

returning the following via Apollo Sandbox and/or insomnia.

```
{
  "data": {
    "sms": "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Response><Message>The Robots are coming! Head for the hills POST POST!</Message></Response>"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To address this issue, and after some back and forth with Twilio support, I used a Twilio function. The flow looks as noted below:

```
(a) Person sending SMS > (b) Twilio webhook > (c) Twilio function > (d) GraphQL response to Twilio function > (e) Twilio function = converts GraphQL response to TwiML > (f) Twilio > (g) Person receiving SMS reply.
```

```js
const axios = require("axios");

exports.handler = async (context, event, callback) => {

  // Create a new messaging response object
  const twiml = new Twilio.twiml.MessagingResponse();

  //call directly to the rest api
  // const response = await axios.post(`https://shop-cooper-deploy.herokuapp.com/api/sms`);
  // twiml.message(response.data); //reply with response to api above
  // console.log(response.data);

  //setup the axios graphql api call
  //define the end point
  const endpoint_production = "https://shop-cooper-deploy.herokuapp.com/graphql";

  //define the headers
  const headers = {
    "content-type": "application/json"
  };

  //define the query
  const graphqlQuery = {
      "operationName": "Query",
      "query": `query Query { sms }`,
      "variables": {}
  };

  //define the axios api call
  const response2 = await axios({
    url: endpoint_production,
    method: 'post',
    headers: headers,
    data: graphqlQuery
  })

  // console.log(response2);
  // console.log('data: ', response2.data); // data
  // console.log('data2: ', response2.data.data.sms);
  // console.log('errors: ', response2.errors); // errors if any

  //convert the response to TwilML
  twiml.message(response2.data.data.sms);

  // Return the TwiML as the second argument to `callback`
  // This will render the response as XML in reply to the webhook request
  
  return callback(null, twiml);
};
```